# Embedded If/Elses vs. Serialized And (&&) statements?

Tags: php, javascript, c++

Is this just a matter of preferences....the code below I'm considering moving to serialized && statments...which is an effective if/else with embedded if/else ' s .

```
Is this a preference or is there a "best practice"?

  function invoke()
    {
    $obj=new validate($this->_protected_arr);
    if($obj->empty_user())
      {
      if($obj->email())
        {
        if($obj->pass())
          {
          if(self::validate())
            {
            self::activate_session();
            $control=new controller_control();
            $control->send('pass');
            }
          else
            {
            new view_message('validate');
            }
          }
        else
          {
          new view_message('pass');
          }
        }
      else
        {
        new view_message('email');
        }
      }
    else
      {
      new view_message('empty');
      }         
    }
```

Comment: Use nested `if` statements when you need different `else` clauses. Otherwise, use &&. It makes the code more compact without sacrificing readability. My $0.02 worth.

Comment: [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)

Comment: Yes, it is a matter of preference. I prefer code that doesn't look ugly and unreadable, so I dislike that piece of code above. But there are some people who prefer it, so what can I say?

Comment: @drd - I agree...below is even more readable

Comment: How is this related to C++, as `$obj` violates the naming rules for identifiers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse your approach..

```
if (!$obj->empty_user) {
 return new view_message('empty');
}

if (!$obj->foo) {
 return new view_message('foo');
}

//Garden of Eden
```

Your code path will only continue if it's safe - this will avoid ugly nested joins and adds flexibility for refactoring. No need to && && && everything.

Comment: If returning is out of the question, you can set a semaphore of sorts, so instead of 'return new foo(); '

You'd do: $error = new foo();

and then wrap the garden of eden with if (!$error) {} - it can get more complicated depending on the verbosity of the actions and error reporting